# Is nginx compilation with jemalloc or tcmalloc memory management more powerful

Tags: c, nginx, malloc, tcmalloc

I'm trying to compile myself NGINX and see that it uses is own memory allocation on top of malloc: ngx_alloc and ngx_calloc.

Is it a good idea to replace ngx_alloc and ngx_calloc with jemalloc or tcmalloc memory management ?

Comment: Don't know the code. But if they built something on top of malloc, it can serve useful purposes. So before trying to remove it, you might want to understand what it does.

Comment: You will have to try it to find out. [The goog says this.](http://itessays.com/other/using-tcmalloc-optimize-nginx-performance.html)

Comment: Although it may gives you performance improvement, but if nginx isn't giving you any problems, probably not. This is for MySQL, but may be useful for you too - http://www.percona.com/blog/2012/07/05/impact-of-memory-allocators-on-mysql-performance/.

Comment: OK, thanks for the links and your explanations.